# CTA to confirm an edit - Save or Update?

Tags: ux-writing

I'm working on a web app and noticed that we have different edit actions scattered across the app (such as editing a phone number on your user profile or editing a rule setting) but we use different verbiage on the CTAs to "complete" the edit. So far I've spotted Confirm, Submit, Save, and Update in different modals.

Trying to make this consistent throughout and I'm debating between `Save` and `Update` (Submit has other connotations within the app and Confirm doesn't feel quite right for whatever reason). Any thoughts or best practices here?

Comment: Contextual awareness would be necessary to tease out the differences between "Save" and "Update". Are these always edits: "Save Changes", "Update"? Are they sometimes adding new information: "Save"? A broader thought—it's best to have consistent CTA's but allow for unique situations that are better supported by alternative CTA's than the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be "Apply," as in applying changes.

It comes down to understanding your users' context and what they expect based on prior experiences with your app and others. You could try to present different and perform a small experiment to gather qualitative feedback on what your users like about each and why. Then, follow up by measuring how often the users return and immediately change those rules within the UI to indicate whether or not they didn't get the result they expected.